# Wamp Server Permission Problems

Tags: wamp, wamp64

I have a WampServer that is working fine but I have a Virtual Host dfor the website but I can't access the website without allowing access to the Home Page

This is the httpd-vhosts.conf file

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted # <- Cant have this reqire local for the main website to work
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName main
    DocumentRoot "e:/wampserver/www/main"
    <Directory  "e:/wampserver/www/main/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I don't want people to have access to the admin page but if I don't let people then the main website doesn't work?